# XmlHttpRequest to PHP changes newline (0x0a) to a literal "\n"

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest, newline, literals

I'm completely baffled by this:

- A string is created in JavaScript with several newlines ("\n")
- It is passed through encodeURIComponent and send to Apache/PHP via XmlHttpRequest
- On the PHP end it arrives as a literal '\n', not a newline.

What I have checked:

- The newlines are correct inside the string, alert(string) breaks correctly.
- After it is encoded, newlines are correctly replaced with %0a.
- Tried both GET and POST (with the variable in the POST body).
- Tried without encodeURIComponent(), same effect.
- Tried \r and \r\n - they also arrive literally.
- Actually counted "\n" and '\n' on the PHP end to make sure it's not "one of those" problems. No doubt, $_REQUEST contains a literal \n.

Things which might be irrelevant, but just in case:

- This all happens inside a window.onerror() handler
- Magic quotes and friends are off

I've looked through the code over and over again and have googled for hours. I got nothing. :( Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Can we see your code? (on both sides)

Comment: You wrote *"On the PHP end it arrives as a literal '\n', not a newline."* - How can you say so? How do you know this? What's the output, which code is creating that output?

Comment: ASCII vs BINARY transfer, or something?

Comment: Unfortunately there's a lot of code around it, because it's inside a huge project, but I traced the way and made sure nothing touches the data.

Let me send parts of it to pastebin.

Comment: Relevant javscript parts: http://ideone.com/M9cIs

Comment: The PHP part checks a boatload of access restrictions, then logs this to a file. Too much to paste. :( But the code does nothing to the $_REQUEST array. I send strpos() searches of "\n" and '\n' to the log instead, to make sure it's not a problem with file logging. It really arrives like that.

Comment: I don't use PHP but i tested for you via .NET and it works fine. string LastId = Request["LastId"]; System.IO.File.WriteAllText("e:\\test.txt", LastId); this correctly inserts the newline in the file. Used a simple jquery .ajax() POST that escape()'ed the value url: "result.aspx", data: "LastId=" + escape(readstring). So it should work ok!

Comment: I think the clue you need might be that %0A or %0D%0A should be newlines when decrypted *no matter what* as that is what those characters *are*.As long as you are sure the AJAX call is encoding it right then your JS is likly fine which means the issue is on the PHP end.

Comment: Thanks. The only realistic options left are the XmlHttpRequest() part and the server side. If this was a common issue with javaScript, Google would have turned something up I think. So what could cause PHP to convert these into literal representations? I double checked, magic quotes are off, but the php.ini is pretty old and recycled. Maybe some long forgotten PHP configuration option?

Comment: Oh damn. I went through the PHP yet another time and found a little hidden loop, which mysql_real_escapes all $_REQUEST variables. :(

Sorry for wasting your time. :(

Comment: Not a waste! Glad you got it sorted :)